# C# form dataset get data after child form closes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, dataset

I'm working on a project with sql server, windows forms and dataset.
Let's assume i have a master form with a datagridview and some other win forms controls bound to a datatable within a dataset, by a binding source. From this form i wish to open another form in which i wish to edit some of the data from the previous form.
I used the showdialog method to wait for the form to close and after that i wish to resync data in the main form (current form at that point).

i used this.mydataset.AcceptChanges(); this.mydataset.GetChanges() and none of them seam to do the work and i'm kinda stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Because DataSet is a reference type and only the reference of the same memory is passed back. When your child form closes it looses its focus (life time/garbage collected) and hence the changes done will be lost. I would suggest pass the main (parent) forms dataset to the child form and change its contents.

Answer (score 0):

**DataSet.GetChanges** will give you not commited memory changes on dataset, it does not get changes from db. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ey25we.aspx

**DataSet.AcceptChanges** method will mark your modified record in dataset as not modified. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges.aspx

You must requery your data from db after child form committed to refresh your data.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Dataset` from the parent form to the child form's constructor as parameter, and keep a form level `Dataset` variable in child form which is pointing (initialized) to that constructor parameter.

Make the changes to the dataset in the child form and make sure you don't dispose off this child form `Dataset` variable (pointing to same Dataset variable in parent form).

Accept the Dataset changes with `AcceptChanges()` method in the child form and when your child form closes, rebind the parent form's grid/control with the original dataset present in the parent form and the changes will be visible in parent.